# How to make a higher-level parallel code/scripts?

Tags: c++, shell

Newbie here.

I have a c++ program XX, note XX is a executable binary here. And now I want this program XX to do the similar job N times but with N sets of different input parameters, and say I have N processors now, then I could let these N jobs run simutaneously on these N processors.

Is it possible from a scripts level to qsub these kind of "parallel" jobs? Or it can be done even on a C++ level? Or any better ideas?

I asked because the XX code I have writen is based on a large project and it is not easy for me to change the mpi part of code. :(

OR do I HAVE TO modify the XX code and the project to have a new algorithm to fit my need.

OR any other advices, like using python or what? that can achieve my goal quickly.

Thanks a lot!

---

I want to add more to my question, to make it clearer.

What if the result of these N are dependent? No, I mean how could I do this,

1st cycle, N jobs on n processors run simutaneously and after a certain time, they all end and give N results, and **I need to do a serial job based on these N results, the result of this will be used as initial condition for the next cycle**, and then move to the next cycle,

2nd cycle,

3rd cycle,

and so on....

Is shell scripts able to do this? Or I'd better to learn to use python? Or I can still use c++???

Thanks :)

Comment: many shells have an external cmd `xargs`, some versions will take a `-n 2-??` argument to say run `n` copies in parallel. Also look for gnu-parallel. Both of these are well documented here on S.O. in Q/A. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [GNU Parallel](http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/) to execute jobs in parallel through a shell script.

Good old `xargs` takes a `-P` parameter that tells it how many jobs to execute at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

The bourne shell can do what you ask just fine:

```
#!/bin/sh
# Run XX 3 times in parallel
XX args&
XX other-args&
XX different-args&
wait  # Wait for all 3 to finish
...
```

Answer (score 0):

[GNU make](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?make) has "-j" switch that allows you to specify how many jobs you want to run simultaneously. So if you can convert the whole thing into gnu Makefile with proper dependencies, you'll be probably able to run specified number of jobs simultaneously. Alternatively you could try some other build system/automation tool. Or you could implement it from scratch in a shell script or something like that. Plain C++ is also possible, as long as you have access to some threads library. Or you could generate Makefile (or another build script) using python. There are many ways to approach this.